# Building lib from source with visual studio or cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, build

I'm trying to build [usrsctp](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp) library. With cmake it builds and don't show any errors. Building with nmake shows this:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.60610.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl -DSCTP_DEBUG -DSCTP_SIMPLE_ALLOCATOR -DSCTP_PROCESS_LEVEL_LOCKS -D__Userspace__ -D__Userspace_os_Windows -DINET -DINET6 -D_LIB /I. /W3 /WX -c user_environment.c
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.
```

After cmake build I have tried to see what is in it with [dll_export_viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) and saw that it is empty. My question is how to build library (.lib) and/ or (.dll) correctly?

## Update #1

CMake output:

```
D:\Desktop\usrsctp>cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" D:\Downloads\usrsctp-0.9.3.0\usrsctplib
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - failed
-- Looking for sys/socket.h
-- Looking for sys/socket.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/queue.h
-- Looking for sys/queue.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/if_addr.h
-- Looking for linux/if_addr.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/rtnetlink.h
-- Looking for linux/rtnetlink.h - not found
-- Looking for netinet/ip_icmp.h
-- Looking for netinet/ip_icmp.h - not found
-- Looking for socket
-- Looking for socket - not found
-- Looking for inet_addr
-- Looking for inet_addr - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SA_LEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_SA_LEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SIN_LEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_SIN_LEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SIN6_LEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_SIN6_LEN - Failed
-- link library: ws2_32
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Desktop/usrsctp
```

Cmake build output:
    D:\Desktop\usrsctp>cmake --build .
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
    [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Build started 2016-04-21 19:20:52.
Project "D:\Desktop\usrsctp\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "D:\Desktop\usrsctp\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building             "D:\Desktop\usrsctp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
....
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:29.86
```

Examination with DLL Export Viewer [image]

Comment: Why are you using Visual Studio 2012 when you tagged Visual Studio 2013? Perhaps that is part of the issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific? My knowlage in programming isn't deep

Comment: Try to generate a Visual Studio project through cmake and build it in VS: cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" ./

Comment: Your output shows that you are compiling with "Visual Studio 2012". However you tagged your question for "Visual Studio 2013" Which one are you using?

Comment: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 2013" ` should be `cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my system's PATH variable was corrupted and nmake was running from old Visual Studio version, which was deleted (why nmake wasn't I don't know). After fixing it, build was successful and lib was fully implemented

Comment: I find that it's best to run nmake / cmake-gui ... from a Visual Studio command prompt for the compiler you want to use. This way you will always have the correct PATH and other settings for your compiler. Although for me I have 4 or 5 different Visual Studio compilers installed (19 years on the job / lots of legacy code).

Answer (score 0):

It's going be super dependent on what library you are trying to build. There isn't a one size fits all solution. 
Looking at the manual for usrsctp what you did using NMAKE makes sense.
All I can give you is more information on the error in particular you are receiving.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt309377.aspx